# Is there a hashing technique that works both ways?

Tags: security, hash, cryptography

**TLDR;**

The hashing function generates a different hash every time for the same piece of data, but it can determine if a particular hash was generated with the piece of data or not.

Eg:

```
hash_func(xyz): abc123
hash_func(xyz): jhg342 // different hash, even if the data was same.

decode_hash(jhg324) == xyz
This gives true, because the hash function determined that jhg324 is indeed the hash of xyz
```

**The Question**

For an Open Source website, I want to store the email in hashed form (because all the users will be public), but the site needs to know if an email was used to register for another account so that it can ensure one account per email.

However, all the emails are from one organization only. This means, they all look exactly like *uid@org_name.com*. This means anyone can run through all the UIDs and find out which hash belongs to which email, and thus, which person.

Therefore, is there a way to hash the email such that the hash knows which email it belongs to, but hashing the same email does not generate the same hash.

P.S. Please note that I cannot use Salting as the site will be Open Source and the salt will be publicly available.

Comment: What would be the advantage of such a hash function? You could still brute-force all potential inputs and based on this reconstruct the e-mail addresses one by one. Based on your description I assume you have not understand how salting works. You don't set a fixed salt for the whole site, instead you assign each entry (e-mail address) an own random salt and store it together with the hash.

Comment: You have used the term "hash" for something that isn't a hash. I would use another term instead, to make it a bit clearer. For example "encode" instead of "hash_func", and "decode" instead of "decode_hash". Then, it is not clear what you mean with e.g. "all the users will be public". The site is open source, does it mean the source code is open? You seem to mean all the data is public... Then better write "all data is public", or "the database is readable by everyone".

Comment: I don't understand the problem that needs to be solved. If all users are public and the usernames are their email addresses, then you don't need to hash or encrypt anything because they are supposed to be public. If you require that each user chooses a public username, but their email address remains private then you write the server-side code in such a way that only the authenticated user is able to see and change their email address. In this case there is also no need for hashing or encryption. Which is also bad because you would need to send a password reset email to them at some point.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't make sense - you're conflating hashing and encryption in a very strange way. What you're describing wouldn't really be a cryptographically secure hash function. By definition, cryptographically secure hash functions are one way. In fact, if you *could* reverse it, there would be little point to using it at all because it would no longer be secure. This would make it possible to brute-force passwords and would "break" passwords that were used in multiple places.

Also, why would you want it to hash to different values each time? That's what you use a salt for.

If you want to be able to reverse it later, just use an encryption algorithm like AES. Even better, many databases even offer features for securely storing sensitive information; see, for example, SQL Server's [Always Encrypted feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/always-encrypted-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15).